# Do C++20 ranges have value(not predicate) version of filter or any_of?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

Classic C++ sometimes picks the _if suffix for predicate algorithms(versus the ones that take value) e.g. `find_if`/`find` `count_if`/`count` and sometimes it does [not](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/g/std-proposals/c/sKA_dDQiU_g/m/uB_4IEN_BgAJ)(for example `any_of` does not have _if suffix although it takes predicate, and there is no `any_of` value version of algorithm).

As far as I can see C++20 `filter` or `ranges::any_of` have no value overload.

I went through entire cppreference page for C+++20 and found nothing, I presume it was just because C++20 ranges library is quite limited (only few views) and it is matching existing functionality (in case of `any_of`).

My best attempt is to just wrap the logic and give it a new name.

```
template <typename Range, typename Value>
static bool contains(const Range& range, const Value& value)
{
    return std::ranges::find(range, value) != range.end();
}
```

edit:
good news:
C++23 has [std::ranges::contains](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/contains)

Comment: Is there something wrong with writing a quick lambda?

Comment: @NicolBolas no, but then we could remove find/count from std ... :)

Comment: You can probably pass `std::bind_first(std::equal_to<>{}, value)` as the predicate.

Comment: ... though it's `bind_front`, as in https://godbolt.org/z/9Mr3dMano

Comment: Pretty sure it doesn't exist because there is no need for it.  As you've shown, it trivial to make your own.  It's even more trivial when you can write a lambda expression in the call site.  You could also use `count` like `if (std::ranges::count(range, value)) std::cout << "elements found";`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Do C++20 ranges have value(not predicate) version of filter or any_of?

No, C++20 does not.  But it is pretty easy to write:

```cpp
std::ranges::any_of(r, [&](auto const& e){ return e == value; })
```

Thankfully, C++23 does introduce a new [`ranges::contains`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/contains) to make this even easier:

```cpp
std::ranges::contains(r, value);
```

---

Or, if that is considered too long, you could add a helper:

```cpp
inline constexpr auto equals = [](auto const& value){
    return [=](auto const& e){ return e == value; };
};
```

That you can use to shorten the `any_of` call:

```cpp
std::ranges::any_of(r, equals(value));
```

Or you could use any number of libraries that let you write placeholder-lambdas, most recently [Boost.Lambda2](https://github.com/boostorg/lambda2):

```cpp
std::ranges::any_of(r, _1 == value);
```

Comment: I like the equals version, since it reads nicely...

Comment: BTW would "in real life"(e.g. your production code or boost) equals actually capture by value? Seems suboptimal wrt performance, but probably safer, since you can save the predicate without thinking about the lifetime of argument...

Comment: do you know if this is in C++23 ? http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2302r1.html

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl It's on track to be at least, we'll see.

Comment: not sure what at least means in this context, but fingers crossed, thank you.